# SSH connection closes as shell fails to load

Tags: ssh, freebsd, shell, zsh

I have FreeBSd running with OpenSSH. I set up everything and the connection via SSH worked perfectly. Then I decided to get rid of some not used ports and I obviously uninstalled one that was used by zsh.

When I log in I get the following:

```
~ # ssh cristian@192.168.1.56
Password:
Last login: Wed Nov  7 21:56:26 2012 from 192.168.1.52
FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE (GENERIC) #0: Tue Jan  3 07:15:25 UTC 2012

Welcome to FreeBSD!

Before seeking technical support, please use the following resources:

o  Security advisories and updated errata information for all releases are
   at http://www.FreeBSD.org/releases/ - always consult the ERRATA section
   for your release first as it's updated frequently.

o  The Handbook and FAQ documents are at http://www.FreeBSD.org/ and,
   along with the mailing lists, can be searched by going to
   http://www.FreeBSD.org/search/.  If the doc package has been installed
   (or fetched via pkg_add -r lang-freebsd-doc, where lang is the
   2-letter language code, e.g. en), they are also available formatted
   in /usr/local/share/doc/freebsd.

If you still have a question or problem, please take the output of
`uname -a', along with any relevant error messages, and email it
as a question to the questions@FreeBSD.org mailing list.  If you are
unfamiliar with FreeBSD's directory layout, please refer to the hier(7)
manual page.  If you are not familiar with manual pages, type `man man'.

Edit /etc/motd to change this login announcement.

Shared object "libiconv.so.3" not found, required by "zsh"Connection to 192.168.1.56 closed.
```

The thing is that I have no monitor nor do I have a keyboard (right now) to solve the problem very quickly...

I tried this to force loading a different shell > [Force SSH to use a specific shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/162018/force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-shell)

Does not work as I get:

```
~ # ssh cristian@192.168.1.56 /usr/local/bin/sh << EOF
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
EOF
Password:
Shared object "libiconv.so.3" not found, required by "zsh"%
```

Any ideas how to solve it without keyboard and monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this same exact error once. I doubt you'll be able to get the root access needed to change your shell remotely. Another, less likely option is to hack your own box and get root privileges.

I had to connect locally via keyboard and monitor and change to the default shell. Never make root use a userland shell. Always let root use the default shell that comes with the system. If you need or want to use a different shell, start it manually after login. This is what I do now.

And remember, don't do `make delete-old-libs` in `/usr/src` unless you absolutely know you won't be needing those libs anymore :-D

Comment: Also remember: always *Always* ***ALWAYS*** have a user account that uses a system default shell (`/bin/sh`, `/bin/csh`, `/bin/tcsh`) so you can get back in if your favorite custom shell goes screwy.

Comment: I accept this answer as it is true :) There was no way to get in via ssh or any other remote way. Actually I had to boot FreeBSD in safe mode and for some reason any changes on the passwd were not taken into consideration. So I created a symlink in /usr/local/bin/zsh that pointed to /bin/csh. This was the only way to get in

Answer (score 2):

If sftp works, I would try to upload a `~/.ssh/rc` file with the commands I need to run (perhaps `echo password | chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`?) and hope that `ssh`, as its manual page states, does execute those commands before launching the user's shell.

Comment: scp does not work. I get the same error

Comment: Not really scp, but rather sftp. Since `sftp` is a subsystem, I think it will not be invoked through the shell.

Comment: I just get "Connection closed". So it doesn't work. I assume this was kinda my last chance?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Try following

```
    ssh username@hostname "/bin/sh -i"
```

That will let you login with sh instead of bash if successful.

**Method 2**

ssh into the box with another user and then su/sudo to regain root access.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` and `zsh` both have a dependency on `libiconv`, so neither will work for you, since you removed it. You can do as John suggested, and tell `ssh` explicitly to run `sh` or `csh`, which are both in the base system and should therefore function correctly, as they have no external dependency on anything in ports.

```
ssh me@there "/bin/sh -i"
```

You now have a shell session, where you can install `libiconv` again. For future reference, it's worth using something like `ports-mgmt/pkg_cutleaves` to remove ports you no longer need - it makes it much harder to shoot yourself in the foot like this!